# Undertow filter to set request header like mod_headers?

Tags: jenkins, wildfly, undertow

My live server is using mod_headers to set a value with a syntax like -

```
Header set MY_FILE "MY_VALUE"
```

Is there an undertow filter to set a value in a request header prior to passing to my application?

```
<subsystem>
   <filters>
      <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/8"/>
      <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
   </filters>
</subsystem>
```

The reason for my question is that I am needing to connect automate my selenium tests on Jenkins, and cant set the value without changing the configuration of my application. My Jenkins environment is not fronted with Apache

Answer (score 0):

Use the `expression-filter` filter.

```
<host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
    ...
    <filter-ref name="set-custom-header"/>
    ...
    ...
</host>


<filters>
    ...
    ...
    <expression-filter name="set-custom-header" expression="set(attribute='%{i,MY_FILE}', value='MY_VALUE')"/>
</filters>
```

documentation:

http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-1.3.0/predicates-attributes-handlers.html

The attribute `%{i,request_header_name}` defines request attribute.